# link a column between two tables

Tags: c#

I am working on a project about School management system by c#, I have an access database contains many tables. 
there is a table named STUDENTS and another table named RESULTS I wnat to link those tables to take the column STDname from STUDENTS into table RESULTS

Comment: Show what you try.

Comment: Give this article a read on how to ask good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Dr.DEVELOPER you have to use join.
i think your query may be like this.

SELECT * FROM STUDENTS INNER JOIN RESULTS on STUDENTS.STDname = RESULTS.STDname

Comment: by this query the two tables joined together by all columns